# How to proof the Pascal's identity using the identity $(a+b)^n=(a+b)^{n-1}a+(a+b)^{n-1}b$?

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> Using the identity $(a+b)^n=(a+b)^{n-1}a+(a+b)^{n-1}b$ to prove the sum property of binomial coefficients:
>
> $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}.$

I don't get the idea of start to solve this.
Can is suppose that the coeficient of $a^{n-k}b^k$ is $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: You'll need induction here.  You can safely assume that $\binom{0}{0} = 1$.

Comment: Note that the number $\binom{n}{k}$ is defined to be the coefficient of $a^{n-k}b^k$ in expansion $(a+b)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you need to use that
$$ (a+b)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}a^{n-1-k}b^k$$
and 
$$ (a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$$
Then using the identity you've been provided you need to prove that 
$$ \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{{\color{red} k}-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, its just a comparison of coefficients:

The coefficient of $a^kb^{n-k}$ in $(a+b)^n$ is $n\choose k$.

The coefficient of $a^{k-1}b^{n-1-(k-1)}a$ in $(a+b)^{n-1}a$ is $n-1\choose k-1$.

The coefficient of $a^kb^{n-1-k}b$ in $(a+b)^{n-1}b$ is $n-1\choose k$.

Now sum up.